# Accessing Ember.js services from browser extension in versions ≥4.0

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, ember.js, firefox-addon-webextensions

In Ember 4.0 and up, access to the Ember global object [is deprecated](https://deprecations.emberjs.com/v3.x/#toc_ember-global). We have a browser plugin for internal debugging/support purposes that would gather some variables from an ember service using this global object and generate a text report that first-line support personel could use when investigating an issue.

Below is a part of the report generator script for Ember 3.28.
This will normally be injected by the extension using [chrome.scripting.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-executeScript) with world 'MAIN', but pasting in the console will have the same effect for reproduction purposes. In Ember 4.0 and up, this will throw a `TypeError` since `window.Ember` is undefined.

```js
var namespace = window.Ember.Namespace.NAMESPACES.find(ns => ns.name === 'acmecorp');
var sessionService = namespace.__container__.lookup('service:session');
var applicationAdapter = namespace.__container__.lookup('adapter:application');
var user = sessionService.get('user');
var userId = sessionService.get('user.id');
var userType = sessionService.get('user.type');
var userTypePath = applicationAdapter.pathForType(userType ?? 'user');
```

Following our upgrade to Ember 4.0 and up, is there any way to access this information from a browser extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a temporary answer in the [Ember Inspector init script](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-inspector/blob/75c5f192c9dbcfde31b5fe5e3077e4a06ae88585/skeletons/web-extension/scripts/in-page-script.js#L32):

```js
const Ember = requireModule('ember')['default'];
```

If you need to be backwards compatible, you can wrap it in a try/catch block like Ember Inspector does

```js
let Ember;

try {
  Ember = requireModule('ember')['default'];
} catch {
  Ember = window.Ember;
}
```

Note that this only applies to Ember environment that expose `requireModule` to the global scope via the `window` object, for other applications/frameworks this does not apply. Also, as NullVoxPopuli notes below, this will break in the future so a better solution, if you are able to change the source, is to expose the relevant service or variables to `window` yourself.

Comment: fyi, this is private API and will break in the future.
You can add this back yourself though in app boot time - and give yourself a known stable variable to access stuff from ember.

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli Of course, I completely forgot I can just expose the relevant service to `window` inside the Ember application itself! Thank you for the suggestion!